# Add a string to a cell WITHOUT using another column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way (formula or whatever) in Excel to simply insert a string into a cell and the cell is automatically updated with an additional string. For example, in A1, all I have to do is type "teststring" and the ***same*** cell automatically updates to "teststring_iscool".

What I'm trying to do is setup a CSV for other employees for easy database upload. I've looked at the left/right and the concatenate functions and these will not work because the database will not accept the random data during the import.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this with VBA.

Comment: @Taosique sure you can, use an event listener and watch for when the cell has change, then test if it already has the post fix, if it doesn't add it to the cell.

Comment: Well, I would welcome the help. While I do have a scripting knowledge, VBA isn't one of the languages I'm familiar with.

Comment: Can you give a real example of the data ('random data') that the database wont accept?

Comment: Well with CSVs, if there isn't a header row with an accept format for data, the database throw an error and no data is imported. Ex(commas separate columns) 
HeaderRow-record,address,fqdn
record,1.1.1.1,mydhcp.mydomain.com

So what I'm trying to do is type "mydhcp" and ".mydomain.com" is automatically added to the same column. The headerrow defines the acceptable information and format. So you can't put words where "address" is. It has to be an IP address.

Comment: For clarification:

Row1:HeaderRow-record,address,fqdn
Row2:record,1.1.1.1,mydhcp.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are. Should a cell value change in `A:A` column, it will check if it ends with `_iscool` and attach this postfix if it does not. Note: add this code in VBA editor to the worksheet code.

```
Const RangeToCheck = "A:A"
Const Postfix = "_iscool"

Public Function StringEndsWith(ByVal strValue As String, _
   CheckFor As String, Optional CompareType As VbCompareMethod _
   = vbBinaryCompare) As Boolean
  Dim sCompare As String
  Dim lLen As Long
  lLen = Len(CheckFor)
  If lLen > Len(strValue) Then Exit Function
  sCompare = Right(strValue, lLen)
  StringEndsWith = StrComp(sCompare, CheckFor, CompareType) = 0
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range(RangeToCheck), Target) Is Nothing Then 'Check only for changes in A:A column
    If Not StringEndsWith(Target.Value, Postfix) Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value & Postfix
    End If
End If
End Sub
```